# Как подставлять каждый раз новую ссылку из текстового файла в curl в цикле

Tags: bash, curl

Есть текстовый файл со ссылками, как брать ссылки из него и использовать?

```
while read -r line; 
do curl $line;
done < links.txt
```

Я пробовал использовать этот код для перебора ссылок, но он выдает ошибку

> curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL

Притом если использовать echo "$line" то код работает.

Comment: Ссылки в каком формате? Ваш пример рабочий.

Comment: `$ dos2unix links.txt`

Comment: `done< <(sed 's/\r//' links.txt)`

Comment: Я новичок и не знаю как добавить к вопросу что ответ найден, но данное решение @aleksandr-barakin, `$ dos2unix links.txt` помогло.

Comment: [дубликаты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=dos2unix)